# How to import modules to hyperledger-composer?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I use `hyperledger-composer` and in the 1lib/logic.js1, at the top, i typed `require('axios')` but when i try to install my network in the composer, i get this `error: ReferrenceError: 'require' not defined or not defined...`

So, please, can you help me to import modules in this file? it could permit me to store my data in a big data as hadoop after transaction validated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composer doesn't support the ability to `require` modules in transaction processor functions. Given that Hyperledger Composer is deprecated I would recommend you go straight to using node.js chaincode in hyperledger fabric which will allow you to include other npm modules (hyperledger composer was, in part, a node.js chaincode runtime to use in conjunction with hyperledger fabric). Would suggest looking at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/write_first_app.html

Answer (score 0):

`require` modules does not support in the hyperledger. You need to write a separate nodejs file for your necessary actions. Look at this [link](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.16/applications/node) for your basic understanding.